# need to split the string using get() and set() methods

Tags: java, string

I have to use getters and setters for this code and 
actually i'm using two classes to get the result

here is Ndc class:

package java4u.com;

```
public class Ndc {


    private String ndcQUAL;
    private String ndcCODE;
    private String ndcUNIT;
    private String ndcQTY;
     String str;
    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }
    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
    public String getndcQUAL() {

        if(str.contains("N4"))
        {
            return "N4";
        }
        else
        {

        return "";
        }
    }
    public void setndcQUAL(String getndcQUAL) {

        this.ndcQUAL = getndcQUAL;
    }
    public String getndcCODE() {
        if(str.contains("N4")){
            int i=str.indexOf("N4");
            str=str.substring(i+2,i+13);
            return str;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }

    }
    public void setndcCODE(String getndcCODE) {
        this.ndcCODE = getndcCODE;
    }
    public String getndcUNIT() {
        if(str.contains("N4")) {
            str=str.substring(i+13,i+15);
            return str;
        }else
        {
            return "";
        }

    }
    public void setndcUNIT(String getndcUNIT) {
        this.ndcUNIT = getndcUNIT;
    }
    public String getndcQTY() {
        if(str.contains("N4")) {
            do {
                int i=str.indexOf(getndcUNIT());
                str=str.substring(i,i++);
                return str;

            } while(str.length()<=35 || str.contains("N4") || str.contains("TPL"));

        else
        {
            return "";
        }


    }
    public void setndcQTY(String getndcQTY) {
        this.ndcQTY = getndcQTY;
    }




}
```

here i'm using str variable and the string will be entered during runtime and the condition is if string contains "N4" value then the loop should be continue else return space.
and I have four methods in this program and
 getNdcQUAL() method should return "N4" if string contains "N4" value
and getNdcCODE() method should display next 11 digits after the "N4" for this case I shouldn't mention str.substring(2,13)..I should find the position of NdcQUAL and from there to next 11 digits will be print..
and getNdcUNIT() method should display next two bytes qualifier after the 11 digits  for this case also I should find the position of NdcCODE and from there to 2 digits
and finally getNdcQTY() method should return the data after the NdcUNIT for this case also I should find the position of NdcUNIT and from there to untill one of the  condition is met

here is my main class

```
package java4u.com;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor.GetterSetterReflection;

public class Test {
    public static String getStr(String str)
    {
        return str;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Ndc ndc=new Ndc();
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            System.out.println("enter a string:");
            br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 


}
```

couldn't understand how to pass the string value from Ndc.java to Test.java also couldn't get how to pass other methods from Ndc.java to Test.java

here is the sample output 
str=N412345678923UN2345.677
it should return 
N4
12345678923
UN
2345.67

please help me!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a constructor. You need to manually set the `str`

If this `N412345678923UN2345.677` is the `br.readLine()`. Then you need to set it in the for your NDC object

```
String str = br.readLine();
ndc.setStr(str);               // now the str is set in your ndc object.

System.out.println(ndc.getndcCODE());
System.out.println(ndc.getndcUNIT());
System.out.println(ndc.getndcCQTY());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first pass the string like this :

```
ndc.setndcQUAL(yourString);
```

then get the required value :

```
System.out.print(ndc.getndcQUAL());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach has one major flaw - you need to execute the methods in a predefined order, else it will extract wrong data. You can however use your `setStr(String str)` method to initialize all proper fields and then just use your getter methods to return the values you've set within your `setStr(...)` method:

```
public class Ndc 
{
    private String ndcQUAL;
    private String ndcCODE;
    private String ndcUNIT;
    private String ndcQTY;

    public void setStr(String str) 
    {
        int pos = 0;

        if (str.contains("N4"))
        {
            pos = str.indexOf("N4");
            this.ndcQUAL = str.substring(pos, pos+=2);
            this.ndcCODE = str.substring(pos, pos+=11);
            this.ndcUNIT = str.substring(pos, pos+=2);
            String data = str.substring(pos);

            // trim the data at the end corresponding to the provided class logic
            int p = data.length();
            if (data.contains("N4"))
            {
                p = data.indexOf("N4");
            }
            else if (data.contains("TLP"))
            {
                p = data.indexOf("TLP");
            }

            if (p > 35)
                p = 35;

            this.ndcQTY = data.substring(0, p);
        }
        else
            this.ndcQUAL = "";
    }

    public String getndcQUAL() 
    {
        return this.ndcQUAL;
    }

    public String getndcCODE() 
    {
        return this.ndcCODE;
    }

    public String getndcUNIT() 
    {
        return this.ndcUNIT;
    }

    public String getndcQTY() 
    {
        return this.ndcQTY;
    }
}
```

To break the loop if no valid `N4` string was entered, you first have to define a kind of loop first and check the `getndcQUAL()` return value if it equals `N4` after you've assigned the input string to `setStr(...)`:

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Ndc ndc=new Ndc();
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try 
        {
            do
            {
                System.out.println("enter a string:");
                ndc.setStr(br.readLine());

                System.out.println("QUAL: "+ndc.getndcQUAL());
                System.out.println("CODE: "+ndc.getndcCODE());
                System.out.println("UNIT: "+ndc.getndcUNIT());
                System.out.println("QTY: "+ndc.getndcQTY());
            }
            while("N4".equals(ndc.getndcQUAL()));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```